# Calculating line integral of a curve

Tags: integration, line-integrals

Say I wanted to integrate a curve f(x) such that f(x) = $x$$^2$ + $y$$^2$ +$z$$^2$ so that the integral of said curve is from this $x$$^2$ $dx$ + $y$$^2$ $dy$ + $z$$^2$ $dz$.

In looking for help, I found this from Yahoo Answers: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111211091146AAl6uVn
although my question is similar in some aspects I am confused how that integral is done with respect to "ds" as opposed to what mine is from the second line of this post. Is it the same thing or totally different?

*And if aforementioned curve relating to my question was composed of line segments from say: $(0,1,0)$ going to $(1,0,1)$ can anyone advise me in how to start it off?*

Finally should the parameterization be provided - or is this something that I will have to figure out myself.

Thank you for your help in advance, I apologise for asking several questions - I am relatively new to this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$x=t, y=cos(2t), z=sin(2t)$

so

$x^2+y^2+z^2=t^2+1$

and

$dx=dt, dy=-2sin(2t)dt$

$ dz=2cos(2t)dt$

which gives

$$ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}=$$

$$dt\sqrt{(1+4)}=\sqrt{5}dt$$

thus , the integral becomes

$$I=\sqrt{5}\int_0^{2\pi}(t^2+1)dt$$

$$=\sqrt{5}(\frac{t^3}{3}|_0^{2\pi}+2\pi)$$

$$=2\pi\sqrt{5}(\frac{4}{3}\pi^2+1)$$

Now for line AB.

we have $A(0,1,0)$ and $B(1,0,1)$.

the parametric equations of line $AB$
are

$x=x_A+t(x_B-x_A)=t$ and $dx=dt$.

$y=y_A+t(y_B-y_A)=1-t$ and $dy=-dt$

$z=z_A+t(z_B-z_A)=t$ and $dz=dt$.

so

$(ds)^2=(dx)^2+(dy)^2+(dz)^2=$

$3(dt)^2$ and $ ds=\sqrt{3}dt$.

the integral is then

$$\sqrt{3}\int_0^1(1+t^2)dt=$$

$$\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}.$$

Comment: Abdallah thank you very much for your reply. I do follow what you said although perhaps I wan't very clear when I asked my my question.

Comment: The ds makes total sense thank you for clarifying that, but I would kindly like to know what if the curve was made of line segments from: (zero,one,zero) going to (one,zero,one) instead of limits 0 to 2Pi. Thank you though.

Comment: in this case you will have x=0+t,y=1-t,z=0+t.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can I ask how you know how to use this as a substitution.

Comment: @nomad609 is it Ok now?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is it okay if I try another example and show my working out to you? Can I ask how you know what the parametric equations this is where I have trouble from progressing at this point. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, what you have written I think is right - only I am not completely sure how you do the step: (ds)2=(dx)2+(dy)2+(dz)2=(ds)2=(dx)2+(dy)2+(dz)2 ; how do you make this judgement.

Comment: Abdallah I really appreciate your help but I want to ask you:   - In the final stage, how do you figure out that the definite integration has limits 0 and 1?   - What does ds mean, the displacement from the origin/distance of the line segment AB?     - And when you remove the x^2 + y^2 +z^2 and replace it with 1+t^2 should it not instead be (3t^2 -2t +1) having squared all the terms.                                           Apolgies for asking a lot - my teacher is not really helpful lmao

Comment: It is Pythogore Theorem